# how to make notification when end incoming call android

Tags: java, android, call, android-notifications

I want to reject call after 1 sec and make notification 
But when i make notification then it give syntax error in  getSystemService
What can i do

Here is my code for rejecting call and make notification

```
private String incomingnumber;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String s[] = { "045193117", "800000000" };
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    incomingnumber = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    try {

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        final com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m
                .invoke(tm);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            if (s[i].equals(incomingnumber)) {
                Runnable mMyRunnable2 = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            telephonyService.endCall();
                            NotificationManager nm= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            Notification notify= new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_low_battery, "Battery Notification",SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis());

                            CharSequence title="Battery Level ";
                            CharSequence details= "Continue with what you were doing";
                            Intent intent= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                            PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getSctivity(con, 0, intent, 0);
                            notify.setLatestEventInfo(con, title, details, pi);
                            nm.notify(0, notify);
                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                Handler myHandler = new Handler();
                myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable2, 1000);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
NotificationManager nm= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

with

```
NotificationManager nm= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

and make the `context` parameter as `final` to access it inner class (here `Runnable`).

```
public void onReceive(final Context context,Intent intent) {
     //
}
```

when you say `getSystemService()` in `Runnable`, it will look for that method in `Runnable` implementation class which is actually not.

Comment: its now fine
but what context i pass to PendingIntent and notification?
I want to show notification when call is rejected

Comment: @user3106818 try using the `Context` returned by `context.getApplicationContext()`... `PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);`